# How to find the category of sentences? List of categories are pre-specified

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I have a list of sentences and list of category.

**My categories are like below:**

Auto,Games, News, Research, Business, Computing, Holiday, Places, Mispelling, URL, Other

**My sample senteces are like below:**

"holiday mansion houseboat"

"verizon wireless"

"select business services"

...

I have to categorize these sentences according to list of categories which are specified above.
I know I should use wordnet, but there are many examples however most of them use training and testing data set. But my data doesn't contain any class information. I should directly categorize sentences according to pre-specified categories. 
 
Anyone can help me or show me a simple example code which finds the category of a sentence?

Comment: I was tempted to flag this as "too broad", but I'm curious to see if anyone can suggest any ready-made packages to do this. An alternative to wordnet would be to calculate word embeddings (and sentence embeddings from them), and find the closest vector and use that as the category. (Don't have time to post a proper answer with example code, sorry.)

Comment: Thank you Darren, I need a starting point for that issue. If you can supply an example code , I will be very grateful for your help